# Selecting by details with MySQL, after join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

First I'll introduce what I'm trying to achieve and how I'm doing it.

I have three tables, `Posts`, `Details`, and `Posts_Details`.

`Posts` is the table where I keep the basic post data, `Details` is keeping the detail instances, with information about the title of the detail, possible values and some information if the detail is required for input, display flags etc. `Posts_Details` is the entity that represents the `M->N` relation which keeps one value of the detail, so it has three attributes, the id pairs of the post and detail and a value.

What I'm trying to setup is, a search functionality.

The first part of the search is simple, I use `Posts.title LIKE '%?%'` and the client is happy with the way it functions, I know its limitations, but this is really basic search functionality for now. The next feature is what brings me the troubles, as I don't feel like I know how to form the relation properly and I'm already behind the schedule to stop working and read up on relations.

I need to create a feature like "advanced search" where the user could not only pick the category and title keyword, but also match the details with drop-down inputs. I'm working with PHP and PDO, but I don't think that's too much relevant here as my problem is more SQL-related.

How I tried to solve this - I'm parsing the get data and collecting it in an associative array with details id as keys and the values as value, so I thought to iterate over the array and append the rules in the WHERE part of the SQL string. I kind of get some result with this approach after I parse the mashed columns, but it doesn't feel right, I feel like I'm doing just a hack-around.

Is there a "righter" way to implement this kind of search by details where I'll make a rule for selecting posts with values from the list of details after the three tables are joined?

Comment: I guess it's easy to downvote the post to oblivion, but I'll appreciate if you tell me what makes this a stupid question and how to improve it or what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: You'll need to provide more details about your tables' structure. Also, what is a "detail"? You sound like it is an attribute (like "blue" or "size 34") since you refer to them by id and not content, but more... details... would help.

Comment: but I did explain the structure -  Details is keeping the detail instances, with information about the title of the detail, possible values and some information if the detail is required for input, display flags etc.

I just left out the context and content as I think it's not relevant to the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subselect.

```
SELECT p.*, d.* FROM ... -- Existing Join
WHERE ... -- Existing Criteria
OR p.id IN (SELECT posts_id FROM Posts_Details WHERE detail like ?)
```

Comment: Nice and much better looking, thanks.

Comment: Sure.  Just a side note-- if your customer can live with '?%' rather than '%?%', you can often radically improve performance.